# Displaying a block element inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a layout consisting of a series of divs that contain an image and some text, where the divs are contained in another div large enough to accommodate 2 of the smaller divs side-by-side, and where the divs run inline so as to naturally organize themselves into two columns but if I add another div to the top of the list everything moves down one spot. Here's a sketch of what I'm trying to do, if my description just confused the hell out of you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1PGq.jpg I realize this is kind of unconventional, but I'm mostly doing it because I can (unless I can't...)

What I have so far is

```
<div class="thumbcontainer">
  <a href="test.html"><img src="images/balls.png"></a>
  <span class="caption">Balls</span><br>
  <span class="description">Balls balls balls</span>
</div>

.thumbcontainer {
  width:            450px;
  display:          inline;
  margin:           0px 20px;
```

But right now displaying the divs as inline only collapses their horizontal margins into the containing div; they're still displayed one after the other in a vertical line. Is what I'm trying to do possible??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display: inline`, use `float: left`. You will probably need to use a clearfix on the `div` that all of the thumbcontainers are in if it has background or borders, however.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! I think I got hung up on display: inline and forgot to think about how flow works. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, on second thought, that wouldn't work, since the page layout is centered (relatively positioned div containing everything, auto margins) so floating the containers would mess up everything else.

Comment: Did I seriously post that comment? I thought I closed the window. Don't worry, I lerned 2 clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

What about soemthing like this?

Or have i missed the point completly?

http://jsfiddle.net/patonar/jxha3/2/